# Honors of open source , in my research

Tags: php, mysql, apache, open-source

I fall in love with Open-Source and it is my research topic.
Can you tell me some honors of open-source world?
I know some of them,such as mysql(DBMS),Ogre(graphic engine),Apache(Web Server) and more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say Linux itself is the biggest one!

And Firefox for web browsers.

http://xkcd.com/198/

Comment: Oh yes,of curse.i forgot the best one.

Comment: Linux is my favorite  OS for its security

Comment: Chromium is hardly a good example of an open source project. It's primarily a Google product, features are mostly dictated by Google management. The fact that patches are accepted from the community is secondary. MySQL obviously also falls in this category -- it's a company's product that is bought and sold.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of scripting languages are Open Source, like Perl, Python, Ruby, AWK, Lua... Then of course the majority of Unix and Unix-like operating systems (to a degree), like FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, OpenSolaris (though Oracle now doesn't seem to publish new versions), Linux, Minix, Plan 9.

But in general: name any IT field and you'll find OpenSource projects for them. Have a look at [FreshMeat](http://freshmeat.net).

Answer (score 1):

Open/Libre Office as the main Open Source alternative to MS Office, or the Gnumeric spreadsheet program as an alternative to MS Excel.

PHP, Perl, Python, and other scripting languages.

Take a look at this [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_software_packages) for OS software covering a whole range of application types